# How to set the startup project for an asp.net core template?

Tags: asp.net-core, templates, .net-core, vsix

I am currently creating a multi-project template, I want to distribute using a .VSIX-extension for Visual Studio. When the extension is installed the user can select my template among the others provided by Microsoft in the "Create a new project" window.

My template consists of three project:

- *ProjectName*.Server
- *ProjectName*.Contract
- *ProjectName*.Client

*ProjectName* is the user-given name while the suffixes "Server", "Contract" and "Client" are fixed. The issue I experience is that when the users create a new project the Client-project is always selected as a startup-project by default. I want the server-project to be selected as a startup-project by visual studio. It looks like following:

[image: The three projects with the client project selected as the startup]

The client project is not the correct startup project, but users don't know that the server project it the correct startup project, so I want to take off the selection and integrate it right into the template, so the correct startup template is selected by VS when creating the project.

I already removed the suffix "Server" from this project, so it is shown as the first project in the solution explorer and I hoped VS would then select it as the startup-project. This did not work unfortunately.

Can anyone give me a hint on how to configure the startup-project in the template?
If you have any questions don't hesitate to comment.

Answer (score 1):

These configurations are stored in the Solution User Options (.suo) file.

You can refer to my steps below to try:

First, Close Visual Studio and find the folder where your solution is.

Second, Open the `.sln` file with a text editor, you see all your projects encapsulated in `Project – EndProject` lines:

[image]
Third, Cut and paste the desired default startup items into the first.

Fourth, Delete your `.suo` file(hidden files: `Solution Folder/.vs/Solution Name Folder/v17/.suo`, I use VS2022).

Finally, Open your solution in Visual Studio.

You can have a try.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely need to [associate a custom IWizard assembly with your project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2022) template, and then explicitly set the startup project by setting the [SolutionBuild.StartupProjects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.solutionbuild.startupprojects?view=visualstudiosdk-2022) to the desired project in your solution.

Once upon a time, I did this using code similar to the following:

```
   VSProject startupProj = FindVSProject(startupProjName);
   sln.SolutionBuild.StartupProjects = startupProj.Project.UniqueName;
```

where FindVSProject was implemented as:

```
   private VSProject FindVSProject(string projName)
   {
      foreach (Project p in _dte.Solution.Projects)
         if (p.Name.Equals(projName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            return p.Object as VSProject;

      return null;
   }
```